# Update multiple rows into wordpress table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I had a table in a form with multiple rows.On click of submit, I made an jquery ajax call (data: `$('#uiWishList').serialize()`) to insertDB.php which has a query to insert into DB. For now the hardcoded query looks like:

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ui_development_tools_wishlist
            (ShortName,  Category, Purpose, Necessity)
            VALUES
            ('$amount', 'val1', 'erwd', 'user1'),
            ('name2', 'val2', 'erwd', 'user2'),
            ('name3', 'val3', 'erwd', 'user3')");
```

1. How can I modify the query such that it inserts dynamic values received from the AJAX.
2. How to get success/failure message after inserting into DB.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're sending the form data via `POST` to PHP using Ajax and your form has fields for three records, you should add the `POST`ed variables to your MySQL query in the PHP like this:

```
$wpdb->query('INSERT INTO ui_development_tools_wishlist
        (ShortName, Category, Purpose, Necessity)
        VALUES
        ('.$_POST['ShortName1'].', '.$_POST['Category1'].', '.$_POST['Purpose1'].', '.$_POST['Necessity1'].'),
        ('.$_POST['ShortName2'].', '.$_POST['Category2'].', '.$_POST['Purpose2'].', '.$_POST['Necessity2'].'),
        ('.$_POST['ShortName3'].', '.$_POST['Category3'].', '.$_POST['Purpose3'].', '.$_POST['Necessity3'].')');
```

This is just an example and does not sanitize the data before using it.

I hope this helps.